# What is the "volume of the gauge group"?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, gauge-theory, group-theory, path-integral, volume

I often see the term "volume of the gauge group" and I am not clear on what this is referring to. For example, in the second volume of Weinberg (page 22), he says

> ...the volume of the gauge group is just the volume of the global Lie group itself times the number of lattice sites."

but what is the volume of the global Lie group?

Informally, it seems the volume of the gauge group is the result one obtains after integrating over all gauges in the path integral. Is this the right idea, if so, can anyone elaborate on this? Secondly, is there a more rigorous definition of the volume of a gauge group (not involving path integrals)?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Weinberg apparently means that the global Lie group $G$ is a finite-dimensional Lie group, typically $G=SU(N)$, while the gauge group ${\cal G}$ is the set of maps from spacetime $M$ to $G$. If $M$ is discretized with finite many elements $|M|$, then the volume of the gauge group $${\rm Vol}({\cal G})~=~{\rm Vol}(G)^{|M|}$$
is the volume of $G$ to the power of the number $|M|$ of lattice points.